# Why can't I do ToList()?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, code-first

I build a model as below. The relationship between Recycler and Account is 1:1.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Quoter> Quoters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.RecyclerRef)
            .WithRequiredDependent(r => r.AccountRef);
    }
}

public class Quoter
{
    public int QuoterId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}

public class Recycler : Quoter
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Account AccountRef { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Recycler RecyclerRef { get; set; }
}
```

But, I get exceptions when I do the either of these queries:

```
var query1 = context.Quoters
    .OfType<Recycler>()
    .Include(r => r.AccountRef)
    .Where(r => r.QuoterId == 1)
    .ToList();

var query2 = context.Set<Recycler>()
    .Include(r => r.AccountRef)
    .Where(r => r.QuoterId == 1)
    .ToList();
```

Exception shows that `ResultType is “Transient.reference[POCOFirst.Quoter]”，but recommanded is “Transient.reference[POCOFirst.Recycler]”`

If I remove the `ToList()`, it works well. But I need a list as the return value of method.

Why can't I do `ToList()`?  Thanks

Comment: If you miss off the `ToList()` and hover the mouse over the `var` keyword what does the tooltip report the type to be?

Comment: It shows the type of query is IQueryable<Recycler>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have stumble upon [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544639/ef4-inheritance-defined-using-queryview-doesnt-work-properly-with-association#details) in EF. Another reference to [the bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/651538/derived-types-to-include-navigation).

Workaround would be to remove the `Include` method.